# How to obtain an access_token (not for app)?

Tags: facebook, api, oauth, access-token, facebook-oauth

I am trying to query facebook reviews from the statistics software R. Could you please let me know how to obtain an access_token? I am not creating an app, and I haven't found any instruction about getting a token for this use. Thank you!

Comment: you need to have app id/app. I am not sure whether you can even access public data without app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have app id before  getting into facebook. So create app and shoot your queries to FB APIs. You can read FB users public feeds but can't access it without authentication. 
[This](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?%20%20%20%20%20%20client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&%20%20%20%20%20%20client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE) will give you access token. More on fb authentication is [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

Comment: Thanks a lot alliswell! I will try it :)

Comment: Hi Alliswell, I tried the url you provided at "This" for access token but only got the following:              {
   "error": {
      "message": "redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI. Check RFC 3986.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}                  could you please let me know how to solve this? Thanks!